# Color Extension with asset catalog colors in SwiftUI crashing preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

The below example compiled and ran fine in simulator/device, but runs into problems in canvas preview. (I have tried clearing cache and derived data)

```
extension Color {
  static let primary = Color("primary")
  static let test = Color(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0)
}
```

This works fine in canvas preview :

```
Text("hi").background(Color.test)
```

But color assets crashes preview:

```
Text("hi").background(Color.primary)


Compiling failed: cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyView' to return type 'some View'
```

(Also as a side note, this seems to work just fine `Text("hi").background(Color("primary"))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is SwiftUI standard `Color.primary` (see below), so I assume the issue is due to ambiguity.

> ```
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> extension Color {
>
>     /// A set of colors that are used by system elements and applications.
>     public static let clear: Color
>
>    ...
>
>    public static let primary: Color      // << here !!
> ```

use instead unique static var name for your custom color, like

```
extension Color {
  static let myPrimary = Color("primary")               // << here !!
  static let test = Color(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0)
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.4

Comment: Ah how silly, looks like there're a few new colors introduced. Thanks